# Laravel 5.5 app outputs a 0 before any content

Tags: git, laravel-5, character-encoding

I'm coding a laravel 5.5 app and in this case I have a stranger issue which I can't locate.

Any output from my application is preceded by `0`, so source code of a single page starts with the following

```
0<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="JoznVUdPwxyz7H8qWd2Np8lPiVld1GTq9BxeC2H2">
```

Even on ajax response I got a `0` before correct data.
eg: `return response('Subscription accepted!', 201);` will output as `0Subscription accepted!`

I suspect that it's related to some kind of encoding because when I first initialized git on this folder, I got a message related to CRLF and LF (I'm coding on a mac with 10.12 macOS), after some research I found a solution using `git config --global core.autocrlf input`, but since that change this weird `0` appears on my views.

I first said *"in this case"* because I'm working on several laravel projects in the same machine, and no one have this issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a user in other forum I have found the reason for that issue.

As supposed it was a typo, but not in any html or template files.

After a deep search I found a controller that begins with `0<?php` and that was responsible for the issue. After deleting that `0` and checked that any `<?php` tag starts in line 1 column 1, the issue is gone.